# Is there a formula for calculating drag coefficient based on the 4 digit NACA airfoil?

Tags: general-aviation, airfoil, drag

Are there any existing formulas that can be used, or maybe some methods to derive an equation that can calculate the drag coefficient based on the NACA airfoil?